# How to attach newel post to stringer below the tread?

Tags: stairs, post

I need to install a new newel post at the top of my stairs but there is not room on the landing for a post, it will have to mount from the tread of the top step.

My plan is to notch out the post at the bottom and sink it through the tread and bolt to the stringer below. My question is, is there a specific way to attach the post without weakening the integrity of the stringer? My main concern is how it attaches to the stringer without losing integrity.

I attached an image to show how I plan to do it.
[image]

Comment: Do you have good access to the underside? This seems to call for a simpson dtt1z/dtt2z attached to the header with a bolt through the post.

Comment: Is is possible to notch both the landing nosing and the tread return? At the area the newel post, what is the material on the riser of the landing? There is usually solid framing under whatever is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use four 5/16" x 3-1/2" lag screws through the stringer into the post, properly piloted, and construction adhesive at all contact points. Spread the screws as far as possible, staying at least 3/4" from any edges, for the best stability.

The bigger concern, though, is the attachment of the stringer to the landing. If that's not robust, your post won't be, either. If possible, add construction adhesive to that joint at all contact points, even inside and around any builder hardware (such as a hanger). Even a heavy bead wrapping the joint and tooled out slightly will add significant strength. You could also add a block to one or both sides of the stringer, against the hanging surface, and embed that in adhesive. Anything along those line will really help give you a solid post.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. I'm going to do everything you said.